# Como agrupar itens de uma array com o mesma categoria em PHP

Tags: php, array, foreach

Eu tenho uma `array` em PHP que segue o seguinte padrão:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=> array(3) {
        ["id"]=> string(1) "1"
        ["categoria"]=> string(7) "Celular"
        ["produto"]=> string(8) "Motorola"
    }
    [1]=> array(3) {
        ["id"]=> string(1) "2"
        ["categoria"]=> string(7) "Celular"
        ["produto"]=> string(6) "Iphone"
    }
    [3]=> array(3) {
        ["id"]=> string(1) "3"
        ["categoria"]=> string(9) "Acessório"
        ["produto"]=> string(10) "Carregador"
    }
}
```

Se eu fizer um foreach, vão vir todas em ordem, mas gostaria de agrupar pelo item "categoria", para retornar o seguinte:

```
<div>
    <h1>Celular</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Motorola</li>
        <li>Iphone</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <h1>Acessório</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Carregador</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Eu tentei fazer um foreach com `if`, mas como é uma array dinâmica, o `if` não resolve pra sempre

Answer (score 1):

Olá, você precisa ordenar o array considerando a chave 'categoria'. Utilize a função **usort** do php.

```
$conjunto[0]['id'] = "1";
$conjunto[0]['categoria'] = "Celular";
$conjunto[0]['produto'] = "Motorola";

$conjunto[1]['id'] = "2";
$conjunto[1]['categoria'] = "Celular";
$conjunto[1]['produto'] = "iPhone";

$conjunto[2]['id'] = "3";
$conjunto[2]['categoria'] = "Acessório";
$conjunto[2]['produto'] = "Carregador";

usort($conjunto, function($a, $b){
    //o segredo está aqui: é feita a comparação de string entre uma linha a próxima (**a** e **b**) 
    return strcmp($a["categoria"], $b["categoria"]);
});
```

Irá ordenar o array assim:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [categoria] => Acessório
        [produto] => Carregador
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [categoria] => Celular
        [produto] => Motorola
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [categoria] => Celular
        [produto] => iPhone
    )
)
```